# python: upload to cloud storage gives InternalServerError: 500 Backend Error

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I have simple python script to upload files to google storage, it takes two arguments one is bucket name and file location path and this script run every two minutes sometime this script get stuck with this error, how can I continue to upload file without my script getting stuck? (maybe retry or catch the error?)

> google.api_core.exceptions.InternalServerError: 500 GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/?projection=noAcl:
>   Backend Error

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import threading
import time
import signal
import argparse
import datetime
import pprint
import os
import gzip
import shutil
from datetime import timedelta
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud._helpers import _to_bytes
from io import BytesIO

WAIT_TIME_SECONDS = 120

class ProgramKilled(Exception):
    pass

def upload_blob(bucket_name, data_path):

    print("This program was started at %s " % time.ctime())
    print(bucket_name)
    files = []
    for r, d, f in os.walk(data_path):
        for file in f:
            if file.endswith(".log"):
                files.append(file)
    for f in files:
        try:
            d, fn=f.split("__")
            s = d.replace("-","/")
        except ValueError:
            print("Faliure")

        with open(data_path + f, 'rb') as f_in:
            with gzip.open(data_path + f + ".gz", 'wb') as f_out:
                shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
        """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
        try:
            storage_client = storage.Client()
            bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
            blob = bucket.blob(s + '/' + f + ".gz")

            blob.upload_from_filename(data_path + f + ".gz")

            print('File {} uploaded to {}/{}.gz'.format(
                f, s, f))
        except exception.InternalServerError:
            print("Upload failed....")

        cleanup(data_path + f)

def cleanup(source_file_name):
    os.remove(source_file_name)
    os.remove(source_file_name + ".gz")
    print("File Removed!")

def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    raise ProgramKilled

class Job(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, interval, execute, args):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = False
        self.stopped = threading.Event()
        self.interval = interval
        self.execute = execute
        self.args = args

    def stop(self):
                self.stopped.set()
                self.join()
    def run(self):
            while not self.stopped.wait(self.interval.total_seconds()):
                self.execute(self.args[0],self.args[1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__,
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('bucket_name', help='Your cloud storage bucket.')

    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command')
    upload_parser = subparsers.add_parser('upload', help=upload_blob.__doc__)
    upload_parser.add_argument('data_path')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    job = Job(interval=timedelta(seconds=WAIT_TIME_SECONDS), execute=upload_blob, args=(args.bucket_name,args.data_path))
    job.start()

    while True:
          try:
              time.sleep(1)
          except ProgramKilled:
              print ("Program killed: running cleanup code")
              job.stop()
              break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Cloud Storage encounters a [500 error](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes#500_Internal_Server_Error) it is recommended to implement [exponential-backoff](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/exponential-backoff). A small number of 500s is expected but if there is a significant number of 500s that are not resolved by the backoffs please [create an issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187243&template=1162869) so we can take a closer look.